# Iterate through files in a directory and extract only specific strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I am trying to iterate through a bunch of text files in a directory and only pull out 4 lines in each text file.

File looks like this:

```
ip=1.1.1.1
port=80

idk=idk

idc=idc

uname=test

whoknows=whoknows

password=test
```

I just want the ip, port, uname, and password. How would I extract that from each file in the directory?

So far I have this, but it just reads the whole file:

```
import os

path = "C:/Users/directory"

os.chdir(path)

def read_text_file(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
        print(f.read())

for file in os.listdir():
    if file.endswith(".txt"):
        file_path = f"{path}\{file}"
        read_text_file(file_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure of the file format, you can iterate through lines in text and search for a certain prefix, for example `ip`. If line starts with `ip`, then return the part of that line after the `=` symbol.

Example of code doing that:

```
text = """
ip=1.1.1.1
port=80

idk=idk

idc=idc

uname=test

whoknows=whoknows

password=test
"""

def get_field_value(text, field):
    for line in text.split("\n"):
        if line.startswith(field):
            return line.split("=")[-1]

print(get_field_value(text, "ip"))
print(get_field_value(text, "port"))
print(get_field_value(text, "uname"))
print(get_field_value(text, "password"))
```

Output:

```
1.1.1.1
80
test
test
```

Answer (score 0):

Using regex you can easily extract necessary data. First read the full text file line by line then  just call the function below with field name an text as parameter:

```
def get_field_value(text, field):
    val = re.search(f"(?<={field}=).*", text)
    if val:
        return val[0]
    return ''
```

Example of calling the function:

```
print(get_field_value(text, "ip"))
```